# Regex Help and Guidance

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to return `"John Doe"` using a regex.

```
string = "{name} John Doe {phone} 555-5555"
```

I really want to master regular expressions. How did you learn?

Comment: The best way to learn regular expressions is to figure a lot of them out by yourself, and only ask on stackoverflow in your times of greatest need.  lupacette's first link below is to rubular, where you can work out regular expressions and test them against arbitrary strings.

Comment: I just pulled out my pickaxe book and found Lookaheads/behinds.  I was able to get what I needed as well by using:  (?<={name} )[A-Za-z]+      Is that a worthwhile use?

Comment: Ah, actually.  That won't work because of name being two words.  Rubular will definitely help me learn these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For things like this it's often best to tokenize and then work with some sort of intermediate representation. `String#scan` is great for extracting data from a repeating pattern:

```
string = "{name} John Doe {phone} 555-5555"

string.scan(/\{([^}]+)\}\s+([^\{]+)/).collect { |s| s.each { |c| c.sub!(/\s+$/, '') } }
# => [["name", "John Doe"], ["phone", "555-5555"]]
```

You could even remap this into a Hash quite simply:

```
Hash[string.scan(/\{([^}]+)\}\s+([^\{]+)/).collect { |s| s.each { |c| c.sub!(/\s+$/, '') } }]
# => {"name"=>"John Doe", "phone"=>"555-5555"}
```

The key to mastering regular expressions is first learning how to read them, then experimenting a lot to see how they behave. Having a tool like Rubular can help with exploration, but there are several good books on the subject worth looking at. O'Reilly has a rather robust selection, and there are others.

My experience comes mostly from Perl which uses regular expressions for all sorts of things.

Comment: Wow.  Exactly what I was looking for.  The solution I had in mind was very brittle and very verbose.  Collecting each for a hash is perfect for what I'm doing.  Thank you!  I'm studying about them now, but I think I do myself a huge disservice when I habitually scan ahead.  Regexes seem to progressively get complicated so it's hard for me to stay motivated.

Comment: A regular expression might have some complicated looking syntax, where  at first it just looks like line noise, but it's really just a way of defining a simple state machine. Once you learn to read and write them the complexity sort of disappears, and their utility spans many, many languages. Most are quite straight-forward and read like "one or more word characters followed by a non-bracket character followed by..." so don't be discouraged!

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways of doing this. Just a first try:

```
/\{name\}(.+)\{phone\}/
```

A test [here](http://rubular.com/r/vTmGsMWsSr). I learned reading [this](http://regex.info/) book.

Comment: Thank you for referring me to Rubular!  Just what I was looking for for testing purposes.

Comment: Yep Rubular is very good for testing and learning.